# neither onActivityResult( ) nor notifyDataSetChanged() work

Tags: android

I've read many answers on the same question but still I do not understand why my code doesn't work properly. I have a problem with (as I think) exchanging data between two activities. 
I have 2 activities - the first contains ListView and an Add button.

When user presses Add new activity starts with the form to fill. When user completes the form he/she presses OK and my first activity starts again (it really does) and it should contain new item (but it doesn't).

This is my first activity:

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<Student> students;
    StudentDatabaseAdapter adapter;
    ListView lvStudentList; 

    ImageButton imgBtnAdd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.database);

        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        fillArrayList();

        adapter = new StudentDatabaseAdapter(this, students);
        lvStudentList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvStudentsList);
        lvStudentList.setAdapter(adapter);

        imgBtnAdd = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagBtnAddStudent);

        imgBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    public void fillArrayList() {
        //code here     
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, WizardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode==2)
            {
                if (intent == null) {return;}
                Student newStudent = new Student(intent.getStringExtra("name"), intent.getStringExtra("surname"),
                        intent.getStringExtra("last_name"), Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("year_of_birth")), R.drawable.default_ava); 
                addStudent(newStudent);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's my second activity:

```
public class WizardActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etName, etSurname, etLastName, etYearOfBirth;

    ImageButton imgBtnOK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wizard);    

        etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        //initializing other edit texts

        imgBtnOK = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnOK);

        imgBtnOK.setOnClickListener(this);          
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("surname", etSurname.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("last_name", etLastName.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("year_of_birth", etYearOfBirth.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);


        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You seem to be missing the way a secondary activity communicates results back to its caller activity.

- `DatabaseActivity.onClick()` should call `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.
- `WizardActivity.onClick()` should just call `finish()` after `setResult()` (remove the `startActivityForResult()` call, it doesn't make sense there). Also notice that the intent you provide to `setResult()` can be an empty intent, i.e. `Intent intent = new Intent();`
- After the secondary activity finishes, `DatabaseActivity` will be back to foreground and the result will be processed by `DatabaseActivity.onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't to start new  activity in WizardActivity

try this :

```
WizardActivity


    ......
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("surname", etSurname.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("last_name", etLastName.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("year_of_birth", etYearOfBirth.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);


    finish();

}
```

and in

```
 DatabaseActivity

add if you want

@Override
protected void onResume (){

......
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I did the first part of your answer and changed my DataBaseActivity as Piovezan sugested - it works fine now! Thank you)

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I mark my question as resolved?

Comment: ok, you are already done this, when you select a response as good response, your question is resolved, that's it